# Mapping an objected oriented model to Clojure

Tags: oop, clojure

Say we are working in an object oriented language and there are two classes X and Y and there is a bidirectional relationship between those classes.

So an instance of X can point to an instance of Y and vice versa.

In Clojure classes usually translate to maps, so we could have:

```
{:type :x :name "instance of X"}
{:type :y :name "instance of Y"}
```

How do we represent a bidirectional relationship between these "objects", without using something like "foreign keys"?  Or is this usually something that is directly delegated to a database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's pretty common to see deeply-nested maps in Clojure that would correspond to hierarchical object trees in object-oriented languages, so e.g.

```
{:type :x
 :name "instance of X"
 :y {:type :y
     :name "instance of Y"}}
```

In fact, this is so common that `clojure.core` provides core functions like `get-in`, `assoc-in`, and `update-in` to facilitate working with such structures.

Of course, this works best when there's a natural hierarchy or ownership relationship between the objects being modeled. In the case of cyclical references this structure breaks down (assuming you're sticking with persistent data structures) -- to see why, try constructing a Clojure map that contains itself as a value.

The way I've typically seen this dealt with is to introduce a layer of indirection using `atom`:

```
(def x {:type :x, :name "x instance", :y (atom nil)})
(def y {:type :y, :name "y instance", :x (atom nil)})
(set! *print-level* 3) ;; do this in the REPL to avoid stack overflow
                       ;; when printing the results of the following calls
(reset! (:y x) y)
(reset! (:x y) x)
```

Comment: wouldn't refs be more suited for this, since their change can be coordinated?

Comment: btw, this code results in "StackOverflowError   clojure.lang.RT.toArray (RT.java:1544)" when I tried it

Comment: Depends on the application. If you just want to set the value once when the map is created, atom probably suffices. If you're going to be doing lots of updates and want to ensure consistency of the graph, then yes, you should probably use refs. The stack overflow is probably from printing the result, since printing an atom will show its value - not sure if `*print-level*` will affect that or not.

Comment: Just checked - you can call `(set! *print-level* 3)` to avoid the stack overflow when doing this in the REPL.